# NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID python using selenium on macOS

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

the program should work like this: when I execute it, it opens a Chrome page and it keeps listening to detect till I press 'q'. After I press 'q' it should click on a button in the page.

The problem is that it doesn't open the page because I get the error NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID.

This is the code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import keyboard

    if __name__ == '__main__':  
        # load chrome
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
        # get product url
        driver.get('url')
        #wait command
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('path').click()
                break
```

Comment: it seems that this is related to the 'url' you are trying to navigate

Comment: I get this error with any URL